# trigger event using after insert

Tags: apex, trigger, after

I Created an object called Percentile with 10 fields and created one more field called Percentage. If I enter a value for one field and if i save it, Then the Percentage field value should be updated with 10 %. Same like that if I enter value for two fields, Then the Percentage field value should be updated with 20 % and vice versa.
I am not getting proper output. Please provide good logic. The trigger which i had used given below.

```
trigger PercentageTrigger on Percentile__c (after insert) {

List<Percentile__c> percent=[select Tilte__c,Name,LastName__c,Email__c,Mobile_Number__c, Industry__c,Father_Name__c,Father_Phone_Number__c,Mother_Name__c,Mother_Phone_Number__c, Percentage__c from Percentile__c where ID IN:Trigger.NewMap.keySet()];

    for(Percentile__c cent:percent){
       f(cent.Name != Null){
            cent.Percentage__c=10;
            update cent;
        }
        if(cent.Name != Null && cent.Tilte__c !=null){
            cent.Percentage__c=20;
            update cent;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you are putting this logic in `after insert` put it in `before insert`  and then you don't need this DML command `update cent;` and **never put DML in for loop**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use before insert so you can skip the extra DML operation

Just check the field is null then increment the Percentage like you did for 2 fields

```
trigger PercentageTrigger on Percentile__c (before insert) {

    for(Percentile__c cent: Trigger.New)
    {
        if(cent.Name != Null){
            cent.Percentage__c=10;
        }
        if(cent.Name != Null && cent.Tilte__c !=null){
            cent.Percentage__c=20;
        }
        //Add for all the fields
    }
}
```

OR you can create a formula field for calculating percentage

---

### Updates

This is not recommend but as per OP request adding this after insert example

```
trigger PercentageTrigger on Percentile__c (after insert) {
    // create a list add the record for update DML
    List<Percentile__c> lstPercentile = new List<Percentile__c>();
    for(Percentile__c cent: Trigger.New)
    {   
        //create new instance and add update percentage field 
        Percentile__c objPercentage = new Percentile__c(Id = cent.Id);
        if(cent.Name != Null){
            objPercentage.Percentage__c=10;
        }
        if(cent.Name != Null && cent.Tilte__c !=null){
            objPercentage.Percentage__c=20;
        }
        //Add for all the fields
        //add into list
        lstPercentile.add(objPercentage);
    }
    //perform update 
    update lstPercentile;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @sfdcweb, but i wanna do the it using after insert event.

Comment: @KSKumar any specific reason for using after insert? it is a best practice to use before insert while updating trigger record

Comment: Yeah..... I am new to Apex. i want to learn trigger and i know we can do it by using before insert event to avoid extra DML operation.

Comment: @KSKumar I have added the example.. I suggest go with before insert approache

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

```
trigger PercentageTrigger on Percentile__c (before insert) {
  for(Percentile__c cent: Trigger.New){
    if(cent.Percentage__c < 0){
      /* reset to 0 */
      cent.Percentage__c = 0;
    }

    if(cent.Name != null){
      /* add % share of this field */
      cent.Percentage__c += 10;
    }

    if(cent.Tilte__c != null){
      /* add % share of this field */  
      cent.Percentage__c += 20;
    }

    /**
     * @todo Add more fields you want to add.. 
     */
  }
}
```

Here you don't need to do any DML operation to update data; and the if conditions need a single condition to check and increment % for that field share;